# Cap deploy - ERROR: Repository not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I've inherited a project and am comfortable with the development side of things, but have poor sysops, and the Capistrano deploy is failing. For a project that has been deployed before by the previous dev:

```
cap deploy:check
```

runs fine, resulting in

```
You appear to have all necessary dependencies installed
```

But when I try to deploy, I get

```
...
ERROR: Repository not found.
...
```

I have:

- Triple checked the github repo address
- Confirmed I can push and pull fine from the repo on my local machine
- Confirmed I can connect fine from the server to github via SSH
- Confirmed I can clone the repo fine on the server
- Tried with agent forwarding both on and off
- Confirmed the repo path matches in .git/config and config/deploy.rb

At the moment, when agent forwarding off, the SSH into github from the server is returning the info for the previous dev, who still has access to the github repo.

```
Hi xxxxxx! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

When agent forwarding is on, I show as being the authenticated user.

Any tips on resolving this? More than happy for a decent URL that goes through troubleshooting this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, figured it out by a process of elimination. It was the following line in 'deploy.rb'

```
set :deploy_via, "remote_cache"
```

When this is commented out it deploys fine. If I uncomment it, it breaks again with the same error. So that certainly seems to be the problem.

I have no idea why this would be happening. But for now, I'll close this.

Comment: I inherited a repository from another developer as well and so regenerated the ssh keys as instructed by Github. Running ```cap production deploy``` always resulted in the same symptoms you found. Does it cache that old private ssh key?

Answer (score 2):

I know I am way late to the game but I just ran into this issue with a project that I moved from Github to Bitbucket. I was able to checkout, update, push/pull from the repo on Bitbucket without issue however my initial cap deploy broke after moving to Bitbucket.

The short answer is that the remote cache on your server needs to be deleted. SSH into your server, and remove the entire `cached-copy` dir found inside the `shared` directory created by capistrano. The location of your shared and releases directory may not be the same as mine but this is all I had to do:

`rm -rf www/shared/cached-copy`

After this I was able to deploy without issue.

Hope that helps someone else that may run into this issue.

Answer (score 0):

For troubleshooting tips--especially because you are deploying from a GitHub repo--I suggest reviewing the GitHub guide to [Deploying with Capistrano](https://help.github.com/articles/deploying-with-capistrano). That guide also links to another you should review on [managing deploy keys](https://help.github.com/articles/managing-deploy-keys).

`default_run_options[:pty]` may be missing or incorrect in `config/deploy.rb`. This could cause the "successful auth, but no shell access for you" error.

Regarding the script still using the previous developer's credentials, the system account the capistrano script logs in with on the server (e.g `set :user, "deployer"`) may have the previous developer's private key in `~/.ssh` which the script may expect to use. If this is the case, you should reconfigure the script to use SSH agent forwarding according to the guides which would have the script start using your keys.

Comment: Thanks Rob, I've had a look through the guides you mention. Maybe I'll try again tomorrow with a fresh head.

My understanding is that the 'GitHub does not provide shell access' message was the standard response on a successful connection?

Also, I've tried it both with, and without, SSH agent forwarding. Same deal.