# Capistrano ERROR: Repository not found

Tags: github, capistrano

Running `cap deploy` returns the error

```
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

> failed: "env PATH=$HOME/.rbenv/shims:$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH sh -c 'if [ -d .../shared/cached-copy ]; then cd .../shared/cached-copy &&
>   git fetch -q origin && git fetch --tags -q origin && git reset -q
>   --hard e54354271256196e54354271256196 && git clean -q -d -x -f; else git clone -q -b new_front git@github.com:myapp.git
>   .../shared/cached-copy && cd /shared/cached-copy && git checkout -q -b
>   deploy ced405a4d2b184ccadf844185e54354271256196; fi'" on
>   192.111.111.111

but when i ssh to the server and run that exact command it works.

I've tried deleting the `cached-copy` and commenting `set :deploy_via, "remote_cache"` as mentioned in [Cap deploy - ERROR: Repository not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11444065/cap-deploy-error-repository-not-found) but nothing works.

thanks

EDIT:

Similar issue:
https://gist.github.com/ParkinT/2432735

Comment: Just upvoted because removing the remote cache fixed my issue thanks commenting set :deploy_via, "remote_cache"

Answer (score 20):

I had to run:

```
ssh-add
```

to add my identity to the authentication agent.

Comment: but my message error was: fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Answer (score 12):

Turns out the problem was with ssh agent forwarding.

https://help.github.com/articles/using-ssh-agent-forwarding

Capistrano was setup

```
ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true
```

Locally I had two ssh keys, and somehow the one used locally was not the same one being used via the forward_agent. If you have a key on the server you can set

```
ssh_options[:forward_agent] = false
```

Otherwise, clear your keys and add just the one you need (on mac, `ssh-add -D` and `ssh-add path/to/key`).

Comment: Adding `set :ssh_options, forward_agent: false` to `config/deploy/production.rb` fixed this issue on CircleCI.